# I'm not getting title of the page,i tried in firefox as well as in chrome

Tags: selenium

I'm not getting title of the page,i tried in firefox as well as in chrome.
This is my package

```
package begin;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Title {
    WebDriver driver;
    public void tite()
    {
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver","C:/selenium-java-3.0.0-beta3/Latest selenium/geckodriver.exe");
        driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
        String titleofthepage=driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(titleofthepage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
       Title obj1=new Title();
       obj1.tite();             
    }   
}
```

Comment: add the property before driver initialization

Answer (score 0):

Need to add wait attributes to driver element.

After creating driver add implicit wait

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver","geckodriverpath");
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You are finding page title immediately after launching web page. Here it will wait 30 secs before finding any element to web page.

Comment: Thanx but i'm still stuck i'm posting new code but same issue please help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property before driver initialization So your code should be :

```
package begin;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Title {
WebDriver driver;
public void tite()
{
      System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver","C:/selenium-java-3.0.0-beta3/Latest selenium/geckodriver.exe");
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
    String titleofthepage=driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(titleofthepage);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{   
   Title obj1=new Title();
   obj1.tite();             
}   
}
```